# List comprehensions with float iterator in F#

Tags: f#, floating-point, list-comprehension

Consider the following code:

```
let dl = 9.5 / 11.
let min = 21.5 + dl
let max = 40.5 - dl

let a = [ for z in min .. dl .. max -> z ] // should have 21 elements
let b = a.Length
```

"a" should have 21 elements but has got only 20 elements. The "max - dl" value is missing. I understand that float numbers are not precise, but I hoped that F# could work with that. If not then why F# supports List comprehensions with float iterator? To me, it is a source of bugs.

Online trial: http://tryfs.net/snippets/snippet-3H

Comment: "To me, it is a source of bugs."
Floats are a source of bugs. When you're using floating point values, you need to pay attention, whatever your language is. List comprehension is nothing more than a series of additions and comparisons.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think it was a good idea to allow list comprehensions over floats. I'm sure it would take special handling to disable it and that's why it is allowed.

Comment: I found old email where in Oct 2008 we decided to cut this feature in favor of a linspace operator.  But then time/priorities/triage kicked in, and this feature was never removed/replaced.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Converting to decimals and looking at the numbers, it seems the 21st item would 'overshoot' max:

```
let dl = 9.5m / 11.m
let min = 21.5m + dl
let max = 40.5m - dl

let a = [ for z in min .. dl .. max -> z ] // should have 21 elements
let b = a.Length

let lastelement = List.nth a 19
let onemore = lastelement + dl
let overshoot = onemore - max
```

That is probably due to lack of precision in `let dl = 9.5m / 11.m`?

To get rid of this compounding error, you'll have to use another number system, i.e. Rational. F# Powerpack comes with a BigRational class that can be used like so:

```
let dl = 95N / 110N
let min = 215N / 10N + dl
let max = 405N / 10N - dl

let a = [ for z in min .. dl .. max -> z ] // Has 21 elements
let b = a.Length
```

Answer (score 1):

Properly handling float precision issues can be tricky. You should not rely on float equality (that's what list comprehension implicitely does for the last element). List comprehensions on float are useful when you generate an infinite stream. In other cases, you should pay attention to the last comparison.

If you want a fixed number of elements, and include both lower and upper endpoints, I suggest you write this kind of function:

```
let range from to_ count =
    assert (count > 1)
    let count = count - 1
    [ for i = 0 to count do yield from + float i * (to_ - from) / float count]

range 21.5 40.5 21
```

When I know the last element should be included, I sometimes do:

```
let a = [ for z in min .. dl .. max + dl*0.5 -> z ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with the precision of floating point values. F# adds dl to the current value each time and checks if current <= max. Because of precision problems, it might jump over max and then check if max+ε <= max (which will yield false). And so the result will have only 20 items, and not 21.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but then List comprehensions with floats are a very bad feature and source of errors...

Comment: For what it's worth, in this particular case replacing all floats with decimals yields identical results.

Comment: @ildjarn: could you give me an example?

Comment: @Oldrich Svec : Put an `m` at the end of every numeric literal in the code you posted to make them decimals, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233193.aspx

Comment: @ildjarn: That is really interesting. Why is that?

Comment: @Oldrich Svec : If you mean, why does decimal suffer from the same issue, I don't know. I only mentioned it to hopefully rule out floating point rounding/imprecision issues, as decimal shouldn't suffer that problem.

Comment: The decimal doesn't work (I ran the code Robert Jeppesen posted, failed as well). You might want to try reverse the list, checking the head, prepending if needed and reverse again.

If you can, you should keep to integers with list comprehension and map them with a function like (fun i -> ((float i) * 9.5 / 11.) + 21.5)

Comment: 9.5/11 does not have a finite representation in base 10, so I'm not surprised it does not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code, if you do:

```
> compare a.[19] max;; 
val it : int = -1
```

It means max is greater than a.[19]

If we do calculations the same way the range operator does but grouping in two different ways and then compare them:

```
> compare (21.5+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl) ((21.5+dl)+(dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl));;
val it : int = 0
> compare (21.5+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl) ((21.5+dl)+(dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl+dl));;
val it : int = -1
```

In this sample you can see how adding 7 times the same value in different order results in exactly the same value but if we try it 8 times the result changes depending on the grouping.

You're doing it 20 times.

So if you use the range operator with floats you should be aware of the precision problem.
But the same applies to any other calculation with floats.