# How to construct a list of float<metre>?

Tags: f#

Usually, when I need to build a list from 0 to 10, I simply do this: [0..10]. This gives me a list of integers from 0 to 10. But this time I would need a list of float from 0 to 10. Is there a way to do that?

```
let testFunc (x: float<metre>) = 
    x

let otherTestFunc =
    [0.0 .. 10.0] // How do I make this return float<metre>
    |> List.map (fun x -> testFunc x)
```

Comment: See [`LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee806527.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I reported this to the F# team a while ago, but you need to specify the step manually when using Measures.

```
let testFunc (x: float<metre>) = 
    x

let otherTestFunc =
    [0.0 <metre> .. 1.0<metre> .. 10.0 <metre>] // How do I make this return float<metre>
    |> List.map (fun x -> testFunc x)
```

Comment: As a side-note, it seems inference can be used here to avoid redundancy : `[0.0<_> .. 1.0<_> .. 10.0<_>]` typechecks as `metre` is inferred by the use of `testFunc`.

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point loops may be dangerous as they hide an accumulating round-off error. See [F# Floating point ranges are experimental and may be deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377078/f-floating-point-ranges-are-experimental-and-may-be-deprecated) for more details.

I believe, the easiest way is to keep your loop in a plain, non-measured `int`, and convert the value within the loop.

```
let otherTestFunc =
    [0 .. 10]
    |> List.map (float >> (*) 1.0<metre>)
    |> List.map testFunc
```

Comment: It's a good point to keep in mind in general, but note that small integers are represented exactly in floating point so it's not really an issue in this case.