# Shorthand to create an array with a floating-point step in F#

Tags: arrays, f#

In F# there is a shorthand for creating an array of numbers. For example, the code

```
[1..10]
```

will create an array containing {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.

Or

```
[-2..2]
```

will create {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}.

Is there any related shorthand for creating an array in F# with a floating-point step? For example, an array like {-2.0, -1.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2} where the step is 0.5? Or is using a `for` or `while` loop the only way?

Comment: It is possible but not a good idea for precision issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377078/f-floating-point-ranges-are-experimental-and-may-be-deprecated?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: That's interesting... I'll have to read into that some more. Cheers for the link!

Comment: Note that `[ ]` creates an immutable list and not an array (`[| |]`) - which is good

Comment: Noted. I'm coming from a C# background, so I still get confused between the different syntaxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
 [-2.0 .. 0.5 .. 2.0]
```

This creates

```
[-2.0; -1.5; -1.0; -0.5; 0.0; 0.5; 1.0; 1.5; 2.0]
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/loops-for-in-expression

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. Thank you very very much! You've made an F# newbie's day!